# How to install Webpack into existing Angular application?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack

I tried to install Webpack into an existing directory of a project using this command:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack
```

However, it returns the following errors:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.2 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN webpack-dev-server@2.4.5 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 but none was installed.
```

How do I fix this and install Webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are running this on Win32 according to

`wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}`

Try to update your node/npm version.

Check out a version manager for node. For windows you can try [this one](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).

**Edit:**

Author did not respond. 
Things tried that might have worked:

```
npm install -f
npm install webpack@2.2.0
```

Comment: Yes, I run this on Win64. So, I have the latest verison node. What next?

Comment: try installing again with `npm install -f` to overwrite the files that exist

Comment: There is one minds here about this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13935

Comment: Will it overwrite project files? A mean Angular component files?

Comment: I tied and get: `npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.2 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN webpack-dev-server@2.4.5 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 but none was installed.
`

Comment: No, it will only remove install files that are being installed from a remote registry. 

No angular components will be overwritten.

Read https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm for more information

Comment: run `npm install --save-dev webpack`. Please mark the answer as resolved when this works.

Comment: please post your package.json

Comment: and run `npm install webpack@2.2.0`